# Upload isn't working on my flask form. IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/blogImages/4IMG_0029.JPG'

Tags: python, forms, file-upload, flask

It's a basic upload implemented into a general blog form.

The configuration:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/blogImages'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

New post including file upload and modification to make file name unique.

```
@app.route('/blog/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if login_session:
            file = request.files['file']
            user = session.query(User).filter_by(email=login_session['email']).first()
            lastPost = session.query(BlogPost).order_by(BlogPost.id.desc()).first()
            nextPostId=lastPost.id+1
            # if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            if file:

                filename = str(nextPostId)+secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                #ADD FILE NAME to BLOG_ID=X
                newPost = BlogPost(title=request.form['title'], description=request.form['description'], time=datetime.now(), user_id=user.id, filename=filename)
                session.add(newPost)
                flash('New post about "%s"  was successfully created' % newPost.title)
                session.commit()


            return redirect(url_for('blog_posts'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        if login_session:
            return render_template('newpost.html')
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

The error I get is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/blogImages/4IMG_0029.JPG'
```

Comment: `'/blogImages'` is in the root of the server (*NOT* relative to the document root). Is that really what you intended? If so, make sure this directory exists and is writeable by the user running this application.

Answer (score 0):

Create the folder **/blogImages/** in your web server or use other existent folder path.

Comment: The folder exists. Sorry I didn't mention that before. It is in the base folder of virtualenv, which is also where the app.py is.

Comment: for **UPLOAD_FOLDER** use absolute path to the folder, for example: `UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/username/flaskapp/blogImages/' `

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I'll check it out. And if i'm about to deploy it on a server? Is there anyway to make it more dynamic. As in, I wouldn't want to keep changing the upload_folder address, every time I upload it.

Comment: Then use `UPLOAD_FOLDER = './blogImages/'` . The path is relative to where you run the app, and depending of how yo do the deploy uwsgi, apache or other it could not work. For that reason is better absolute path.